# JitPack build failed due to Android SDK license agreement

Tags: android-library, jitpack

I have an Android library on my Github: [CalendarView](https://github.com/shuwnyuantee/CalendarView), which I forked from the original author. I published my Android library on [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/#shuwnyuantee/CalendarView).

I created `releases` in GitHub, with `git tag`. For `release tags: v1.0, v1.1`, the `build` on `Jitpack` was successful.

However, for version `v.12`, `build` on `Jitpack` failed with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2, Android SDK Platform 25].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The full error log is [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/shuwnyuantee/CalendarView/v1.2/build.log).

Without fixing anything, I created another `release tag: v1.3` on Github. Then triggerred `build` on `Jitpack`. The build was successful without error.

Any idea why the above error pops up & goes away by itself? Any recommendation for fix if it pops up again next time? Thanks!